# deploy machine learning application with flask on Cpanel : "500 Internal Server Error An internal server error has occurred."

Tags: python, flask, cpanel, http-status-code-500

I'm trying to add an python application with flask to an existing website on Cpanel, after adding all the files of the app and installing the requirements, I received the 500 Internal Server Error An internal server error has occurred.
the error log gives this :

[image]

I found some solution about the .httaccess to add the following to it :

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE]

but still the same ERROR